# Make two child DIV's match the height of a single parent DIV?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website mainly for educational purposes. When it comes to designing something I kinda go OCD on it and like it to be perfect ;) . I've come across an issue I can't seem to fix myself so I'm hoping some of you guys could provide a fix or know of a website which covers this sort of thing.

On there I have parent DIV and two child DIV's inside...

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="container-left"></div>
    <div id="container-right"></div>
</div>
```

Both the child DIV's have their own content in them and both vary in height. The way my website is designed `#container-right` has to be equal or greater in height than `#container-left` for the design to look right.

Here's a link to the website: [www.lulzorg.com/?p=w7ws8](http://www.lulzorg.com/?p=w7ws8)

Here's a website capture showing what I mean: [skiroid.com/website_capture.jpg](http://skiroid.com/website_capture.jpg)

Thanks for your time! :D Any questions? please ask!

Answer (score 3):

Couple of ways:

```
#container { height: 100px; }
#container div { height: 100%; }
```

or

```
#container { display: table; }
#container div { display: table-cell; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/